# System.IO.File.Copy never overwrites

Tags: c#, .net

In my WinForm I would like to copy/overwrite files.

When the destination file does not exist, the file gets created OK. When the file already exists, it never gets overwriten. Path is on my local computer.

There are no exceptions thrown, and I gave full access to "Everyone". Same issue with FileInfo. Only when I delete the file first it gets created!

My Code:

```
//File.Delete(path + "gauche.png");
try
{
    // FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(path, Num_Gauche.Value + ".png"));
    //fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(path, "gauche.png"), true);
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(path, Num_Gauche.Value + ".png"), Path.Combine(path, "gauche.png"), true);
}
catch (Exception ex )
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "There are **NO** exceptions thrown"?

Comment: "Path is on my local computer" You expect code behind in a web app to manipulate files on your local computer?  Is the web server on your computer too?

Comment: Yes, no exception and no overwriting!

Comment: It is a WindowsForm! and I am logged as ADministrator.
From CMD it works:
C:>copy 2.png gauche.png /Y

Comment: excuse, I corrected it!

Comment: I did not manage to format it properly!Sorry!
Code makes no exceptions!

Comment: the third parameter: overwrite=true is set, so files should be overwritten!

Comment: I suggest you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code as shown should work, so something has clearly been left out. Do a console app, and use the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce your issue.

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @mason I deleted my irrelevant comment which discusses a different overload.

Comment: Where do I have to send the MCVE?

Comment: In your question. Just provide the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce your issue, preferably in a console app so we can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: In my question!! How????

Comment: my guess is that you are overwriting the file with the same contents. Look at the last written date on the file

Comment: @Seli17 You copy and paste the relevant code into your question. What you have now in your question isn't complete, which is why I asked you to create an MCVE.

Comment: No, they are png-Files, all from same time and size, but a different gray.
(from white to black in 10 steps)

Comment: It is alomost complete:
Path is a local folder on my D-Drive.
What is missing are the png-Files.
I will try with txt-Files....

Comment: I created 1.txt   2.txt  and so on..... they are corrrectly overwriting the destination-file.
=>So it works with this txt-files but not with the png-files!!!!

Comment: I saved now my png with different time, it seems to work.
Thanks for the brain storming

Answer (score -1):

It could be an ownership issue. If the file was created by another user, your process may not be able to overwrite it. Usually like if the file was created by a installer/MSI that you may have issue to overwrite it by another process.
I will just enable that piece of code to delete the file prior to create it if that works.

Comment: He stated he gave the necessary permissions in his question.

Comment: Ownership is different to permissions. Look at file property, it can be configured per user. By default admin user has all permissions to access but it is not always correct.    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659(v=ws.11).aspx